# Excluding all hidden files with .dockerignore

Tags: docker

I'm trying to exclude from my Docker image all hidden files (starting with a dot) from all directories of the project.

To exclude `.git` and `.gitingore`: `.git*`

To exclude all `.keep` files: `**/.keep` works

For all hidden files, I tried: `**/.*`, But that excludes all files containing a dot, like `**/*.*` does.

Answer (score 5):

[.dockerignore files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerignore-file) try to follow Go's [filepath.Match](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) rules with the addition of a glob like `**` matching any directories in a path. So they aren't exactly the same as glob patterns, or even trying to be. In fact, Docker implemented [its own parser](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/b248de7e332b6e67b08a8981f68060e6ae629ccf/pkg/fileutils/fileutils.go#L132) so it's not even using `filepath.Match` any more.

Using `dir/.*` and `dir/*/.*` works as expected. But `dir/**/.*` doesn't seem to work all the time.

This [specific issue should be resolved](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/29014), but I think I've seen the same behaviour in 1.13.1 in certain circumstances.

So with a `.dockerignore` of `dir/**/.*` the file `dir/file.ext` will be excluded but `dir/subdir/file.ext` will be included.

This is probably worth opening a [new issue with Docker if you have a specific reproducible case on 1.13](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues).

Answer (score 2):

[The issue has been fixed](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/29043) but the commit has not been merged into a released branch yet.